# Get limited data from $unwind mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have a chats collection which given down below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a44e6545818041cde24aac9"),
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-23T07:46:29.201Z"),
            "message" : "Hii",
            "userId" : "000000"
        }, 
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-23T12:46:29.201Z"),
            "message" : "Bye gtg ttyl",
            "userId" : "111111"
        }, 
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-24T07:46:29.201Z"),
            "message" : "Bye Take Care",
            "userId" : "000000"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-23T07:46:29.201Z"),
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "facebookId" : "000000",
            "unread" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "facebookId" : "111111",
            "unread" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

When I do this following query in nodejs

```
chats.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$messages" },{ $unwind : "$users" } ])
```

I get an array which is something like this in which unwind opens my array something like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a44e6545818041cde24aac9",
        "messages": {
            "createdAt": "2017-12-23T07:46:29.201Z",
            "message": "Hii",
            "userId": "000000"
        },
        "createdAt": "2017-10-23T07:46:29.201Z",
        "users": {
            "facebookId": "000000",
            "unread": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a44e6545818041cde24aac9",
        "messages": {
            "createdAt": "2017-12-23T07:46:29.201Z",
            "message": "Hii",
            "userId": "000000"
        },
        "createdAt": "2017-10-23T07:46:29.201Z",
        "users": {
            "facebookId": "111111",
            "unread": 0
        },
    }, //And so on.
]
```

But can I  only get the objects after unwind where `messages.userId !== users.facebookId`

something like the following object directly from MongoDB when i fetch data

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a44e6545818041cde24aac9",
        "messages": {
            "createdAt": "2017-12-23T07:46:29.201Z",
            "message": "Hii",
            "userId": "000000"
        },
        "createdAt": "2017-10-23T07:46:29.201Z",
        "users": {
            "facebookId": "111111",
            "unread": 0
        },
    },{
        "_id": "5a44e6545818041cde24aac9",
        "messages": {
            "createdAt": "2017-12-23T12:46:29.201Z",
            "message": "Bye gtg ttyl",
            "userId": "111111"
        },
        "createdAt": "2017-10-23T07:46:29.201Z",
        "users": {
            "facebookId": "000000",
            "unread": 0
        }
    }, {
        "_id": "5a44e6545818041cde24aac9",
        "messages": {
            "createdAt": "2017-12-24T07:46:29.201Z",
            "message": "Bye Take Care",
            "userId": "000000"
        },
        "createdAt": "2017-10-23T07:46:29.201Z",
        "users": {
            "facebookId": "111111",
            "unread": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `{$match:{ 'messages.userId' :{ $ne: '$users.facebookId'} }])`

Comment: @Veeram it is not working

Comment: Can I see your query ?

Comment: chats.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$messages" },{ $unwind : "$users" },{$match:{ 'messages.userId' :{ $ne: '$users.facebookId'}}}]).exec(function(err, data) {
    res.send(data);
  });  @Veeram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below one

```
db.coll3.aggregate([{
            $unwind: '$users'
        }, {
            $project: {
                messages: 1,
                users: 1,
                'messages': {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$messages',
                        as: 'item',
                        cond: {
                            $ne: ['$$item.userId', '$users.facebookId']
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },{ $unwind : "$messages" }
    ])
```

This is in mongoshell. I noticed that number of zeros in your records aren't equal. Please make sure you are not confused with them even if above queries by @veeram and @Astro were giving you correct results, if you tried them

Answer (score 1):

You can include `$match` stage to get only those documents as a result which match this condition:

```
db.chats.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$messages" },{ $unwind : "$users" }, {$match:{ 'messages.userId' :{ $ne: 'users.facebookId'} }])
```

Comment: this looks weird for this pair atleast: messages.messages: 111111 and users.facebookId:111111

Comment: why ? can you explain ?

Comment: Couldn't find any difference though